# Add new elements to Pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor that looks like this:
[image]

I would like to add 0 to each inner tensor. So we have something like[0.1111, 0.6667, 0].
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use torch.cat

Comment: PyTorch tensors are backed by contiguous regions of memory. Growing one will in all likelihood require that the memory (a bigger chunk) is reallocated and the old data is copied in. You can do this using for example `torch.cat`, or by simply creating a new tensor of the right size and copying in the old tensor. However, you might wanna reconsider your algorithm if you find yourself relying on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
z = torch.zeros((10,1))
torch.cat((your_tensor,z),1)
```